# PHP work out age in years and months from timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running this SQL:

> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE())
>        as age FROM members

to work out users ages from a timestamp in the database.

I have 3 columns `(dob_year / dob_month / dob_day)`

the above query works out the age in years but I need it in years and months. So rather than age being 10 years, it should say 10 years and 2 months old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE()) 
      as 
        years, 
        (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE()) - 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE())*12) 
      as 
        months 
      FROM 
        members
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work  giving you 2 columns

```
1. years
2. months


SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE()) 
as years,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, 
    TIMESTAMPADD(YEAR,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE())
    ,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day)),CURDATE()) 
as 
   months 
FROM 
   members
```

[reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Comment: Not 100% sure the last part will work but try and lets see what happens :)

Comment: this one doesnt work, the previous one displayed things like 13 years 166 months (13 years is 166 months)

Comment: this is not working be cause first it finds years and that years is directly used in months, and it is not allowed. Instead of years, there should be whole expression of years in finding months.

Comment: ahh yeah ofc that slipped my eye :) ty :)